# No transmission via IP

Tags: windows, ip, tcpip, tcp, icmp

I'm using netstat on Win XP to check protocol transmission details for TCP, IP, and ICMP. There is transmission only in TCP. No transmission in ICMP is understandable since it's for errors and I assume that there were none, but why is there no transmission through IP?

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -s` shows per-protocol statistics, includng those for IP.

On my XP PC (see below) the **IP Output Requests** = **ICMP messages sent** + **TCP segments sent** + **TCP segments retransmitted** + **UDP datagrams sent**.

```
C:\>netstat -s

IPv4 Statistics

  Packets Received                   = 857789
  Received Header Errors             = 0
  Received Address Errors            = 0
  Datagrams Forwarded                = 0
  Unknown Protocols Received         = 0
  Received Packets Discarded         = 5
  Received Packets Delivered         = 857784
  Output Requests                    = 857442
  Routing Discards                   = 0
  Discarded Output Packets           = 44
  Output Packet No Route             = 0
  Reassembly Required                = 0
  Reassembly Successful              = 0
  Reassembly Failures                = 0
  Datagrams Successfully Fragmented  = 0
  Datagrams Failing Fragmentation    = 0
  Fragments Created                  = 0

ICMPv4 Statistics

                            Received    Sent
  Messages                  8           30
  Errors                    0           0
  Destination Unreachable   0           22
  Time Exceeded             0           0
  Parameter Problems        0           0
  Source Quenches           0           0
  Redirects                 0           0
  Echos                     2           6
  Echo Replies              6           2
  Timestamps                0           0
  Timestamp Replies         0           0
  Address Masks             0           0
  Address Mask Replies      0           0

TCP Statistics for IPv4

  Active Opens                        = 656
  Passive Opens                       = 360
  Failed Connection Attempts          = 4
  Reset Connections                   = 28
  Current Connections                 = 32
  Segments Received                   = 857250
  Segments Sent                       = 856900
  Segments Retransmitted              = 62

UDP Statistics for IPv4

  Datagrams Received    = 495
  No Ports              = 50
  Receive Errors        = 9
  Datagrams Sent        = 450
```